# Why were we able to make alcohol with little cleanliness and no sanitizer?

Tags: yeast, sanitizer, distillation

When I was younger I lived in Missouri for a bit and I met a guy who ended up having me help him make "shine" (that's what he called it) in the woods fairly often - I guess you could say that I was just his assistant, but I assisted in every step. For me it was an adventure until I realized how stupid I was being. Anyways, we didn't keep things particularly clean and we never used any sanitizer that I ever saw. I didn't even know that you needed to use a sanitizer until I started reading about home distillation online recently. I also never saw any turbo yeast or anything like that. As far as I know, he had been doing it that way for years before I met him. How can it be that he/we was/were always successful?

Comment: Isn't distillation off-topic?

Comment: The question isn't really about distillation, but the answer is! So is it off topic?  Its not a question about brewing for sure.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turbo yeast is faster than beer yeast, so no bacteriae have much chances to proliferate.
2. Even if there is a bacterial or wild yeast infection no one cares, as that fermented stuff is distilled.

For that matter, whisky distillers don't sterilize their wort before fermenting it, and some level of bacterial infection is considered necessary for the traditional taste.

Comment: Turbo yeast can ferment at higher alcohol levels and that also kills pretty much everything.

Answer (score 1):

You were distilling the product.  Sanitation isn't important because you aren't consuming any of the mold or bacteria that was in the wash.  Its contribution on flavor is debatable depending on how efficient the distillation was.